# PostCSS with Gulp throws an error after update

Tags: node.js, gulp, postcss

I updated npm packages using ncu (npm check updates). After all the packages were updated, the build process is throwing error.

After going through my gulp task and removing a PostCSS plugin called "Precss", all things work. I also tried reverting this plugin alone to an older version, and it works.

Unfortunately Precss is the main plugin that I need, in order to use SASS like features in my CSS. This plugin must have the latest version because another plugin called postcss-calc dependent on Precss plugin.

Below is the error that is thrown:

```
Node#before is deprecated. Use Node#raws.before
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 9): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
(node:8447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 10): TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same exact issue, solved by fix dependencies in my package.json instead of use 'latest' versions...

There are my modules version, hopes it helps:

```
$ npm list --depth=0
├── autoprefixer@6.7.7
├── browser-sync@2.18.11
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-autoprefixer@3.1.1
├── gulp-clean@0.3.2
├── gulp-concat@2.6.1
├── gulp-concat-css@2.3.0
├── gulp-cssbeautify@0.1.3
├── gulp-cssnano@2.1.2
├── gulp-csso@3.0.0
├── gulp-load-plugins@1.5.0
├── gulp-notify@2.2.0
├── gulp-plumber@1.1.0
├── gulp-postcss@6.4.0
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
├── gulp-sourcemaps@2.4.1
├── postcss-sorting@2.0.1
└── precss@1.4.0
```